# How to check if drop-down is selected in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a validator function looping through to check and see if all inputs have been filled out, but I also need to check if the dropdown's have been selected as well. I would like to write that into the same function.

```
    function validateSave (){
        // reset status
       var good = true                                       
       $('.errormessage-left').removeClass('active-left')
       $('input').removeClass("warning")
       $('input').each(function(){
           if ($(this).val() == "") {
           console.log("found an empty");
           good = false
           $(this).addClass("warning")
           $('.errormessage-left').addClass('active-left'),
           $('.modal').addClass('modal-active'); 
        }
    })
    console.log(good)
    return good
    }
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: The best way would be to forget custom solutions and go with HTML5 input validation attributes and/or existing jquery form validation plugins.

Comment: Have you checked jQuery api site ? http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/ (as i see you write in jquery) or just $("select option:selected")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `val()` on a dropdown (`<select>` element) just like an input element, so just include it in your selector

```
$('input, select').each(function(){
```

Comment: Just me or that seems "incomplete"?

Comment: @Braiam - The rest of the code the OP already has inside of the `each` iteration callback. Check to see if the value of the current element is `== ""` and then perform some logic. There didn't seem to be much point in duplicating the rest of the `each` callback since the logic will depend on the OP, but the question was how to tell if a value had been selected in the dropdown, and the answer is that `.val()` will be equal to `""` on a select element just like on an input element so you can just include it in the selector and use it the same inside of the callback.

Comment: My original html was 

    <select class="action">
      <option value="" disable selected>Choose an action</option>
      <option value="100">Schedule an interview</option>
      <option value="200">Send a form/email</option>
      <option value="300">Accept/Reject</option>
    </select>

Taking out the disable selected and then doing 

    $('input, select')

solved my problem

Comment: Not 100% but it just gave me idea of selecting how many dropdowns are selected in a whole page out of all dropdowns. Helped me through the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

Assuming the first element is :"please choose..."

`if ($(".myDDL").get(0).selectedIndex>0)...`

or

`if ($(".myDDL").prop('selectedIndex')>0)...`

Comment: Thanks for the help

my html had 
    <option value="" disable selected>Choose an action</option>

Taking away the disabled selected and adding ('input, select') worked

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add this to your loop:

```
if ($(this).prop('type')=='select-one'){
   if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex')==0){
      console.log("found an empty");
      good = false
      $(this).addClass("warning")
      $('.errormessage-left').addClass('active-left'),
      $('.modal').addClass('modal-active'); 
   }
}
```

Comment: $(this).selectedIndex will fail

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input').each(function(){
           if($(this).prop('selected') == true){
              // selected item
           }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="whatever">
<select>
    <option value="">Choose One...</option>
    <option value="choice1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="choice2">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="choice3">Choice 3</option>
</select>
```

Then your jQuery can figure it out like this

```
$('input, select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        alert('Cannot be blank!');
    }
    else{
       //proceed
    }
}
```